# small o(1) notation

Tags: analysis, limits

It's probably a vey silly question, but I'm confused. Does o(1) simply mean $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(n)}{\epsilon}=0$ for some $n>N$?

Comment: You should clarify your question. Even though people may be able to guess what you want to ask, there's no need for anybody to guess. I don't think it will be too hard for you to spend some more time improving your question.

Comment: I thought the question is clear enough. How exactly do you want me to improve it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This should be a comment to chazisop's answer; I don't have enough rep to make it.

Chazisop, your quantifiers in 1 are the wrong way round, in fact there are two problems.  Firstly, saying $\forall k>0 : f(n) \leqslant k$ is simply equivalent to saying $f(n) \leqslant 0$.  The right definition for $o(1)$ is that
$$
\forall k > 0\ \exists N\ \forall n \geqslant N :\; |f(n)| \leqslant k.
$$
**Note:** the $k$-quantifier appears at the start, this is non-negotiable!  Secondly, notice the absolute value signs around $f(n)$.  If you are only thinking of nonnegative functions (e.g. the running time of an algorithm) you can omit them, but not for arbitrary functions.

To the OP, no, that's not what $o(1)$ means.  There are two problems with what you've written: firstly, what is $\epsilon$? Secondly, what are the $n$ and $N$ supposed to be (I don't mean the $n$ in your limit)?  You need to think about this statement more carefully.

The definition of $f(n)$ being $o(1)$ is that $$\lim _{n \to \infty} f(n) = 0.$$  That means that for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists $N_\epsilon$, depending on $\epsilon$, such that for all $n \geqslant N_\epsilon$ we have $|f(n)| \leqslant \epsilon$.  I guess this definition is probably where your $n>N$ comes from.

Comment: Corrected my response. Although I would find out the quantifiers error eventually, thanks for the mod signs, which is something I have never encountered before.

Comment: @chazisop By "mod sign" Matthew means the absolute value signs, and (I mean this neutrally) it's surprising you haven't seen them before, so I suspect you might have misconstrued his intended meaning. Absolute value is sometimes called "modulus" especially when referring to the absolute value of complex numbers, but I find this disfavorable because absolute value means only one thing, while modulus is more commonly used to indicate the base of a modular congruence relation. I actually hadn't encountered "modulus" being used to mean absolute value prior to seeing this response.

Comment: @TrixieWolf you're right that absolute value is more common - I updated the answer.

Answer (score 9):

It probably means $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(n)}{1} = 0$$

Comment: doesn't f(n)=o(g(n)) mean $limf(n)=|\epsilon \cdot g(n)|$?

Comment: see this: http://www.math.osu.edu/~fowler/teaching/handouts/ibl-analysis/little-oh.pdf

Comment: whether there is $\epsilon$ or $1$ in the denominator does not matter at all...

Comment: $f(n) = o(1)$ as $n \to \infty$ means $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(n) = 0$.  No need for $\epsilon$ or $N$.  But, of course, the *definition* of the limit can involve $\epsilon$ and $N$.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $f(n)\in o(1)$ . This can be interpreted using to equivalent definitions:

1. $\forall$ constant $k>0$ $\exists$ $n_{0}$ such that $\forall n \geq n_{0}$  , $n \epsilon \mathbb{N}$, $|f(n)| \leq k$.
2. $\forall$ constant $k > 0$ , $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{f(n)}{k} = 0$ , which implies that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(n) = 0$.

Comment: $n_{0}$ must be the same for all n and k. So the order is $\exists n_{0} \forall n \geq n_{0} \forall k > 0$. I just mention my background because there may be slight variations on how asymptotic notation are used in analysis that I am not aware of.

Comment: Isn't it possible to come up with some pseudo-random algorithm that has constant running time? For example, if I want a quadruple of numbers between 0 and 1 which make up a nonzero determinant, one randomly generated quadruple will work almost certainly.

Comment: @Joseph In certain models it is possible to have constant time algorithms. They would be however $O(1)$ and not $o(1)$. As I mentioned in my answer, an algorithm cannot have a running time less than 1 step,whereas $\forall k$ includes constants less than 1. $o(1)$ of course makes sense for analysis.

Comment: $o(1)$ can come up in expected time analyses of algorithms, e.g. (fictional) $T(n) = 2n + 3 + \frac{1}{n}$. Also, my standard comment: note that $f(n) = o(1)$ is abuse of notation. A function can not equal a class of functions.

Comment: No, $n_0$ is allowed to depend on $k$ in the standard meaning of $o(1)$. $f(n)=1/n=o(1)$, but there is no value of $n_0$ which works for all $k$. For any particular $k$ you can choose $n_0(k)$. See 5316's answer.

Comment: Corrected. I consider "=" abuse of notation too, but I thought that it was common to use it out of the TCS scope. Modified anyway. Although I removed the algorithms part, I believe $o(1)$ is exotic for algorithms.