# Brauer Algorithm

Tags: computer-science

I'm working on a problem and I'm looking at an equation:

$lg(n) + (1 + o(1))(lg(n))/(lg(lg(n))$

All I want to know is, what does o(1) mean?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Be careful copying. Is it $O(1)$ or $o(1)$? They mean very different things.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation

It's intuitively a function that grows MUCH slower than $1$/constant, of $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} f(x)=0$

Comment: It is a lowercase o.

Comment: @pj6444 see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29100/small-o1-notation