# Limit: Meaning of $o(1)$

Tags: limits

What does it mean in $f(x,k) = e^{ikx} + o(1), x \to + \infty$ the o(1)? Does it mean the function tends to $e^{ikx}$ plus an other term that does to 0? Then why do we even need the term?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation

Comment: Yes, with $o(1)$ you can just express it with a limit, but the little-o notation is very useful in other cases.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29100/small-o1-notation

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $o(1)$ indeed means “something which tends to zero”.

According to the usual definitions of limits, the limit of a function is a **number**, not another **function**, so it's not correct to write
$$
\text{“}
f(x) \to e^{ikx}
\quad\text{as}\quad
x \to \infty
\text{”}
.
$$
(How can you have something left that depends on $x$, *after* you have let $x \to \infty$?)

What you **can** write is
$$
f(x) - e^{ikx} \to 0
\quad\text{as}\quad
x \to \infty
,
$$
and the notation
$$
f(x) = e^{ikx} + o(1)
\quad\text{as}\quad
x \to \infty
$$
is just a synonym for this (which may be more convenient in some contexts, if for some reason you don't want to bring the term $e^{ikx}$ over to the other side).