# Does $\log(f(x))\sim \log(g(x))$ implies $f(x)\sim g(x)$?

Tags: limits, analysis, asymptotics

Let $f,g: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be two real-valued functions. Suppose $\log (f(x)) \sim \log(g(x))$, as $x\to \infty$, i.e., $$\log(f(x)) = (1+o(1))\log(g(x)) \text{ as } x\to \infty\quad (\clubsuit)$$

From this post [small o(1) notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29100/small-o1-notation), we have that $h(x)\in o(1) \implies \lim_{x\to \infty} h(x)=0$, with $h:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$,

From $(\clubsuit)$, we have $f(x) = g(x)\cdot e^{o(1)\log(g(x))} = g(x)\cdot(g(x))^{o(1)}$ as $x\to \infty$. However, can we conclude that $(g(x))^{o(1)}\sim 1$ and therefore $f(x)\sim g(x)$ as $x\to \infty$?

Does knowing $\lim_{x\to \infty} g(x)$ can help?

Comment: No; for instance $f(x) = x$, $g(x) = x \log x$

Comment: @Kyky, do you mean that $\ln(g(x)^{o(1)})=o(1)\ln(g(x))$ and therefore if $|g(x)|\to \infty$, we have no guarantee that $o(1)\ln(g(x))\sim 0$? since $o(1)$ implies that we have a function whose limit goes to $0$, so we should not be able to get $1$, right?